# Invoking Multiple functions in parallel is working intermittently in ksh script

Tags: shell, ksh

Invoking Multiple functions in parallel is working intermittently in Bash script.

I'm trying to invoke multiple functions in Parallel in a bash script. 
All the functions contain the same code and logic, but the functions `call_bpa` and `call_inv` are working intermittently.
getting the error [: argument expected in the function call_bpa or call_inv.

### Flow:

Submitting CPA program.
IF CPA program completed then
call functions call_po , call_bpa, call_inv in parallel.
IF call_po and call_inv completed  then
 call function call_chk
end if;
end if;
check all the functions completed, then

### print completed.

```
#!/bin/ksh
p_userid=$2
p_max_runtime=$5
p_apps_pwd=$6
p_resp_name=$7
p_sleeptime=$8

# removing temp file of the previous run
if [ -f XXPRP_PATH/PRGPOPULATE_CTRL_FILE ] 
then

echo "$(date) - removing temp file of the previous run "
rm -r XXPRP_PATH/PRGPOPULATE_CTRL_FILE
fi


logfile=$(mktemp XXPRP_PATH/PRGPOPULATE_CTRL_FILE)
chmod 777 XXPRP_PATH/PRGPOPULATE_CTRL_FILE


call_bpa()
{
-- bpa program submission logic
echo 1 >> $logfile 
}

call_po()
{
--po program submission logic
echo 2 >> $logfile 
}

call_inv()
{
--inv program submission logic
echo 3 >> $logfile 
}

call_chk()
{
--chk program submission logic
echo 4 >> $logfile 
}

p_pop_max_wait=$(( p_max_runtime * 60 * 60 ))
echo "$(date) - Max wait for the weekend run is $p_pop_max_wait secs"
--CPA program submission logic
# If CPA program  completed, the only submit rest of the programs
if [ $p_phase_code = "C" ]
then
call_bpa & call_po & call_inv   
lv_chk_exit="N"

waittime=0
while  ! grep "1" $logfile  ||  ! grep "3" $logfile 
  do
  echo "$(date) - Waiting for INV or BPA program to complete "
    sleep $p_sleeptime
    waittime=`expr $waittime + $p_sleeptime`
    if [ "$waittime" -eq "$p_pop_max_wait" ]
      then
      lv_chk_exit="Y"
      exit 0
    fi
done
fi

# If  INV and BPA functions, the only submit chk request set
if [ $lv_chk_exit = "N" ]
then
call_chk
fi

lv_cons_exit='N'
waittime=0
while  ! grep "1" $logfile  ||  ! grep "2" $logfile ||  ! grep "3" $logfile 
  do
 echo "$(date) - Waiting for all the Parent request sets to complete  "
    sleep $p_sleeptime
     waittime=`expr $waittime + $p_sleeptime`
    if [ "$waittime" -eq "$p_pop_max_wait" ]
      then
    lv_cons_exit="Y"
      exit 0
    fi
done

echo "$(date) - removing temp file created"
rm -r $logfile

echo "$(date) - Population Program request sets completed successfully"

# Program submission logic which is referred in each function



 call_bpa()
{

# submit Purge Populate BPA STG tables request set 

p_request_set=`sqlplus -s <<EOF
apps/$p_apps_pwd
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  l_success boolean;
  e_submit_failed exception;
  l_request_set_id number;
BEGIN
  fnd_global.apps_initialize($p_userid,$p_resp_id,$p_resp_appl_id);
  l_success:=fnd_submit.set_request_set('XXPRP','XXPRPBPAPOPLTSTG');
  IF not l_success then
    raise e_submit_failed;
  END IF;
  l_success := fnd_submit.submit_program ('XXPRP', 'XXPRPPOPULTBPASTG','STGBPA10');
  IF not l_success then
    raise e_submit_failed;
  END IF;
  l_success := fnd_submit.submit_program ('XXPRP', 'XXPRPPOPULTCUSTOMSTG', 'STGBPA20','BPA');
  IF not l_success then
    raise e_submit_failed;
  END IF;
    l_request_set_id := fnd_submit.submit_set (NULL, FALSE);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_request_set_id);
EXCEPTION
  when e_submit_failed then
    dbms_output.put_line('FAILED');
END;
/
exit
EOF`

p_request_set_id=`echo $p_request_set | cut -f1 -d" "`

if [ $p_request_set_id = "FAILED" ]
  then
  echo "$(date) - Program exiting "
  exit 1
fi

echo "$(date) - BPA STG tables Request ID: $p_request_set_id submitted sucessfully"

waittime=0
while [ "$p_bpa_phase_code" != "C" ]
  do
  p_req_codes=`sqlplus -s <<EOF
apps/$p_apps_pwd
  set feedback off
  set heading off
  SELECT phase_code,status_code
  FROM  fnd_concurrent_requests
  WHERE request_id = $p_request_set_id;
  exit
  EOF`
  p_bpa_phase_code=`echo $p_req_codes | cut -f1 -d" "`
  p_status_code=`echo $p_req_codes | cut -f2 -d" "`
  if [ $p_bpa_phase_code != "C" ]
    then
    sleep $p_sleeptime
    waittime=`expr $waittime + $p_sleeptime`
    if [ "$waittime" -eq "$p_pop_max_wait" ]
      then
      echo "$(date) - BPA STG concurrent request set $p_request_set_id has not completed after maximum wait time of $p_pop_max_wait seconds with status_code of $p_status_code"
      exit 0
    fi
  fi
done

if [ $p_status_code = "E" ]
  then
  echo "$(date) - BPA STG concurrent request set $p_request_set_id has completed with a status of ERROR"
  exit 1
elif [ $p_status_code = "W" ]
  then
  echo "$(date) -  BPA STG concurrent request set $p_request_set_id has completed with a status of WARNING"
fi

echo "$(date) - PRaP Purge Populate BPA STG concurrent request set $p_request_set_id has completed successfully"



echo 1 >> $logfile 

}
```

Comment: Presumably your question is how to make the functions always work? It will be easier to help if you show us actual code and errors.

Comment: my code is too long. 2048 characters and i could not able to paste due to character limitation

Comment: Saying "the functions ... are working intermittently" is very vague to diagnose. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i have just uploaded the code. Please have a look

Comment: Hi.. still we are getting the same error. Sometimes call_bpa function will break.some times call_inv will break. Its completely random i.e getting error [: argument expected. I ran the script in debug mode ksh -x script.ksh. As i observe some times, getting error when connecting to the sql sessions. But some times it will skip some statements while executing . Please help. Is it a issue with parallel background processes?

Comment: You say "getting the error [: argument expected in the function call_bpa or call_inv." but you have deleted all the code from those functions so how is anyone supposed to help you?

Comment: For a start you should run your code through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix all the warnings it shows you

Comment: Hi .. at the end of the code i have written code for call_bpa() function. All the functions use same logic, only difference is program name and numbers writting into log file

Comment: Where is `p_phase_code` set? If it isn't `lv_chk_exit` won't get set.
`lv_chk_exit`, `$p_request_set_id`, `$p_bpa_phase_code`, and `$p_status_code` should be double-quoted in the `if` tests.

Comment: p_phase_code is set  as p_phase_code=`echo $p_req_codes | cut -f1 -d" "`. Ig program submitted successfully, then p_phase_code will contain 'C' . I have tested by giving double quotes for $p_request_set_id, $p_bpa_phase_code, and $p_status_code in if condition still its failing .  Note : Its not failing consistently . Its failing intermittently . Not able to simulate why its breaking

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with `bash` when you are running under `ksh`?

Comment: sorry. I have tagged both Bash and shell . I thought there wont be much difference.

Comment: The error is that one of your tests is failing. If you don't know which one, trying echo'ing parameters to a debug log before every test, so you can find out which has the bad value. eg. `echo "p_status_code=E :: [$p_status_code]" >>debug.log` on the line before `if [ "$p_status_code" = "E" ]`, etc.

Comment: I have submitted script with ksh -x scrip.ksh, its printing null value p_request_set inside the function call_bpa , call_inv. Its completely random behavior . Sometimes call_bpa will print null , some times other functions print null value . Since p_request_set value is null ,    getting argument expected error while hitting if condition.                                          p_request_set_id=`echo $p_request_set | cut -f1 -d" "`

if [ $p_request_set_id = "FAILED" ]

Comment: Your functions have calls to `exit` in them -- they will kill your script.  Your functions are also not all being run in parallel (or with concurrency).  Please check my answer about proper implementation of concurrency in shell script.

Answer (score 2):

On any bourne-like shell...

```
cpa_program() { echo cpa_program; }
call_po()     { echo call_po;     }
call_bpa()    { echo call_bpa;    }
call_inv()    { echo call_inv;    }
call_chk()    { echo call_chk;    }

cpa_program

{
    call_po &
    call_inv &
    wait
    call_chk
} &
call_bpa &
wait
echo completed
```

You can place a `sleep 1;` in any of the functions above to see how the parallelism works.

1. You can serialize everything by getting rid of `&` everywhere.  Try that first and parallelize after fully getting the serial execution to work.
2. Simplify your code and debug incrementally.  When I debug I use echo in front of commands while I debug to see what would be invoked on each line before I enable my script fully.
3. Make sure the function calls are on separate lines and the `&` is at the end of each line as written if you want parallel execution. Doing `call_po & call_inv & call_foo` on one line is not correct.
4. Calls to `wait` are important -- they **block** until parallel execution steps complete.

Comment: still failing. I have posted the code. Please check

Comment: Thanks @Michael Back. Hi.. still we are getting the same error. Sometimes call_bpa function will break.some times call_inv will break. Its completely random i.e getting error [: argument expected. I ran the script in debug mode ksh -x script.ksh. As i observe some times, getting error when connecting to the sql sessions. But some times it will skip some statements while executing . Please help. Is it a issue with parallel background processes?

Comment: @Ajay - points 3 and 4 are my guesses as to why your script is having issues - I think your script is racy and it also needs simplification. You may also have an error handling issue.